# Apple Mach-O Linker Error for a Blank project. Just frameworks imported

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, ios8

[image: When I uncomment it there are 24 errors]

[image: When Parse.setApplicationId is commented out, there are no errors]
When Parse.setApplicationId is commented out, there are no errors

When I uncomment it there are 24 errors
This is Strange, I can't understand. I didn't write any code. Just a blank project with frameworks imported.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are issues with the parse framework,  make sure you have the latest version and that it is built for the version of swift you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue of the dependency frameworks not being included properly. You could try cleaning the build directory in Xcode (option + command + shift + K) and also looking in to your project settings and included frameworks.

Having worked with Parse quite a bit, I would highly recommend using cocoapods to manage your dependencies for you because it'll get very tedious.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is cocoapods. I've heard about it many times. Searched for it to know what it is, But couldn't understand the use. I know it is useful because many devs use it. I know that CocoaPods is the dependency manager for iOS projects. But, can you tell me clearly about it how is it useful to me. Thanks Russell

Comment: Sure thing. Cocoapods (https://cocoapods.org/) is just a dependency manager. What that means is that instead of having to download frameworks or libraries online and then configure project settings, you can add them with one change to a `podfile` for your project. Inside the podfile you list the frameworks you want and then from the command line run `pod install` which will automatically download, install and configure your project. For example, to add Parse to your project, you would just add `pod 'Parse'`. When `pod install` is run, it will also install Bolts and other dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed libsqlite3.dylib